# Как выполнить код в консоли на удаленном windows, имея rdp?

Tags: windows, java, unix, консоль, rdp

Добрый день.

Дано: логин, пароль к rdp windows сервера.
Нужно: выполнить код в консоли на удаленном сервере, имея эти сведения.

Как решить задачу?

Преветствуется любое консольное решение под nix (java, python, etc).

**Обновление**

Искал в гугле, решения пока не нашел. Мне нужно выполнить команды на удаленном виндовс сервере (имея в наличии rdp login/password) из консоли текущего.

Comment: @Родион Преображенский, ХэшКод это не фриланс биржа. Перефразируйте ваш вопрос, уточните, что сделали сами, что не получилось.  

`properJavaRDP is an open source Java RDP client for Windows Terminal Services`
http://properjavardp.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

1. Login & Passwd - Аддмина ??
2. Бат файл создать и поставить в автозапуск под данной учеткой, в противном случае, можно поставить запуск по расписанию.

Answer (score 0):

А в чем у вас проблема? заходите по `RDP` открываете консоль и вводите свои команды. Все зависит от того хотите вы это делать руками или автоматически по-расписанию.
По расписанию - через планировщик заданий - там можно либо запускать батник, либо прямо код в консольном режиме сразу, почитать краткий мануал можно тут:

https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc721931(v=ws.11).aspx